# Add text to hidden input value based on selection from dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

Although this seems simple I am struggling to find a real solution. What I need to do is add/append text to the value of a hidden input based on the selection of a dropdown. The value in the dropdown will be added/appended to a randomly generated ID as a suffix that should look like this "12345678_myBrand". This is very easy to do, BUT I need the text (not the entire value) to change when the dropdown selection changes rather then simply adding/appending the most recently selected dropdown option.

Here is what I'm doing

HTML:

```
<input id="myHiddenField" type="text">
<select id="brand">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="First Choice">First Choice</option>
    <option value="Second Choice">Second Choice</option>
    <option value="Third Choice">Third Choice</option>
    <option value="Fourth Choice">Fourth Choice</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var brand = $('#brand');
    var hiddenField = $('#myHiddenField');
    hiddenField.val(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000));

    brand.change(function() {

        hiddenField.val( hiddenField.val() + "_" + brand.val() );

    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wo6a5nkf/2/

Obviously I don't want to keep adding/appending the suffix to the id so how do I simply change the text without adding/appending every single option selected???

Answer (score 1):

You may use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 var brand = $('#brand');
  var hiddenField = $('#myHiddenField');
  hiddenField.val(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000));
  
  brand.change(function() {
  
   hiddenField.val( hiddenField.val().split('_')[0] + "_" + brand.val() );
  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="myHiddenField" type="text">
<select id="brand">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="First Choice">First Choice</option>
<option value="Second Choice">Second Choice</option>
<option value="Third Choice">Third Choice</option>
<option value="Fourth Choice">Fourth Choice</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the hiddenField value to look for an underscore.  If one exists, then re-use that number.

```
brand.change(function() {
    var parsedHiddenField = hiddenField.val().split('_');
    if (parsedHiddenField.length > 0) {
      hiddenField.val(parsedHiddenField[0] + "_" + brand.val());
    }
  });
```

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/419fhgm3/1/).